# how to create loopback models and model properties from sample json data files

Tags: json, strongloop

I need to create loopback models for data I have currently in plain text json files. I don't want to type property by property in ARC, but I'd like to create a slc script instead, by taking as input template the existing json data files. But can't find any guide on how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The api is documented at https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Creating+models+from+unstructured+data. You can add a yeoman generator to import json data for generating models.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i had already read the linked doc and did not relate it to my situation, seems to me that i need to make a deeper look. However, the second part looks more promising... Where can I find some info and examples on how to create such a generator?